# Cycles left some squares in final render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, customization, gpu, artifacts

does anybody know why I get this final render in CUDA Cycles. I get this results when I try to render with CPU and GPU together, like they have set different number of samples or CPU try to catch up the GPU and don't render all samples:
[image]

GPU or CPU only render doesn't leave those squares, but what is interesting is that number of sampling doesn't change anything...I get the same noisy render when I set 400 samples and 20000 samples and the render time doesn't change, in both samples cases time is the same and I couldn't achieve better results.

I use latest Blender version 2.92, CPU Intel i5, 16 GB of RAM, Nvidia GTX 1050 Ti...win 10.

Is it possible that some features of Octane render engine, which I try day before and uninstall afterwards, has left behind and messed up my cycles render?

I have just noticed that the number of render samples are somehow limited to 32???

Any Idea?

Comment: do a factory reset on your blender. you will not lose any file but any adjustment to blender will be lost like: startup scene and your costume themes, key shortcuts, favs etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why my render is limited to 32 samples:

[image]

At some point I wanted to override the material and I left 32 samples in Material override samples field.

But I still have those artefacts (tiles) which my CPU or GPU left behind :(, and had some strange line in the middle of render...

[image]

Comment: Create a new scene and place some primitives around and then do a hybrid render.  See if this problem is present in a new file

Comment: I've already try that...and it works normally.... :(

Comment: Hmm... you know I've seen the 1050 give some strange behavior once or twice, maybe there's a certain driver version you should go for, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found out what cause the problem!!!

One of my area light which I have use to imitate lights of the wall lamp, has been partly inside of the object:

[image]

That cause the artefacts and lot of noise. Now, the image is crystal clear!

[image]

I hope this will help others with same problem ;)